# Lex :Match multiple regex at the same time

Tags: c, regex, compiler-construction, lex, lexical-analysis

I have the code below:
I want to count the number of characters using

```
(.)   {charCount++;}
```

and at the same time count the number of words using

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])*    {wordcount++;}
```

is this possible using lex rules, or do I have to count it "manaully/programmatically" using  the file stream in c code . Basically is there code for "continue matching/ regex"

```
%% 
[\t ]+  ; //ignore white space
"\n" ;  //ignore next line // 
([a-zA-Z0-9])*    {wordcount++;}
(.)   {charCount++;}
%% 
int yywrap(void){} 
int main() 
{    
    // The function that starts the analysis 
    yyin=fopen("input.txt", "r");
    yylex(); 
    printf("The number of words in the file is %d and charCount %d",count,wordSize);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of characters matched by a rule is available in `yyleng`, so you can do this:

```
[ \t\n]         ;
[a-zA-Z0-9]+    { ++wordcount; charcount += yyleng; }
.               { ++charcount; }
```

But (f)lex is not designed to do multiple scans over the input. So there's no simple general solution.

FWIW, I'd use `[[:alnum:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `[[:space:]]` instead of `[ \t\n]`.